# for文を用いて辞書型データをそれぞれ適切なフォームに入れたい。

Tags: python

**実現したいこと**
data = (title, lead, url, author)という4つのロウデータが存在します。このデータの塊を1つとして計100個分のデータセットがエクセルにあります。これらを1つずつ取り出し、さらにその4つを適切なフォームに入れたいです。そこで辞書型データをどのようにデータに分けて、繰り返しでセルを次の数字にしていくのか、またそれをsend_keyに入れていくのがわかりません。どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

マルチポスト先：[リンク](https://teratail.com/questions/361924)
**現在できていること**

以下のように1つずつセルを取り出し、入力することはできました。

```py
v_excel_title = ws['b8'].value
v_excel_lead = ws['f8'].value
v_excel_url = ws['g8'].value
v_excel_author = ws['d8'].value
time.sleep(1)

v_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
v_c_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
v_lead = driver.find_element_by_id('id_heading').send_keys(v_excel_lead)
v_url = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_url').send_keys(v_excel_url)
v_author = driver.find_element_by_id('id_creator').send_keys(v_excel_author)
```

あとはこれを自動で次の、次のデータと進むようまとめる必要があります。以下で辞書型にするところまではできました。あとはこれをforで取り出して、上記のコードにするだけです。

```py
#read excel

file = input("ファイルを入力してください:")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
ws = wb["XXX"]

data_list = []
header_cells = None

for row in ws.rows:
    if row[0].row == 1:
        header_cells = row
    else:
        row_dic = {}
        for k, v in zip(header_cells, row):
            row_dic[k.value] = v.value
        data_list.append(row_dic)

for data in data_list:
print(data_list)

>>dict_keys(['title', 'date', 'author', 'creator url', 'lead', 'url', None])
>>dict_keys(['title', 'date', 'author', 'creator url', 'lead', 'url', None])
>>dict_keys(['title', 'date', 'author', 'creator url', 'lead', 'url', None])
```

しかし、これをどうそれぞれv_excel…のデータに入れて、繰り返しでセルを次の数字にしていくのか。またそれをsend_keyに入れていくのがわかりません。どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？

---

**追記**

```py
def send_keys(driver, data):
    v_excel_title = data['title']
    v_excel_lead = data['lead']
    v_excel_author = data['author']
    v_excel_url = data['url']
    
v_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
v_c_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
v_lead = driver.find_element_by_id('id_heading').send_keys(v_excel_lead)
v_url = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_url').send_keys(v_excel_url)
v_author = driver.find_element_by_id('id_creator').send_keys(v_excel_author)
```

どうしてもここだけわからないのですが、これをどのようにエレメント見つけて入れることができるようになるのでしょうか？

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import time

import openpyxl


#read excel
file = input("ファイルを入力してください:")
sheet = input("ワークシートを入力してください:")


#get to login Page

driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
TARGET_URL = ""
driver.get(TARGET_URL)
time.sleep(2)

#input signin information
user = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username").send_keys("")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password").send_keys("")
signin = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("")
signin.click()

def create_data_list():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True)
    ws = wb[sheet]

    data_list = []
    header_cells = ws[1]

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row):
        row_dic = dict([(k.value, v.value) for k, v in zip(header_cells, row)])
        data_list.append(row_dic)
        return data_list
        
create_data_list()

for data in data_list:
    v_excel_title = data['title']
    v_excel_lead = data['lead']
    v_excel_author = data['author']
    v_excel_url = data['url'] 

v_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
v_c_title = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_title').send_keys(v_excel_title)
v_lead = driver.find_element_by_id('id_heading').send_keys(v_excel_lead)
v_url = driver.find_element_by_id('id_content_url').send_keys(v_excel_url)
v_author = driver.find_element_by_id('id_creator').send_keys(v_excel_author)
    
#save
save_draft = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.action-save.button-longrunning")
save_draft.click()
```

Comment: 「適切なフォーム」の"適切"とは、どういう事を意味しているのですか？
回答者が理解できるような説明が無いと、質問者の意図に沿った回答が得られないと思います。

Comment: 「これをどのようにエレメント見つけて入れることができるようになるのでしょうか？」…ええと、もしかして `id_title` や `id_content_title` というのは実際の HTML ページに書かれている DOM の id ではない、という事でしょうか…？

Comment: いえ、その認識で間違いありません。ただどのように書けばよいのかわからなくってしまって。書き方としては上記のもので合っていますか？

Comment: @Kazuhiro はい、正しいです。ところで、これは arXiv の様なサイトから論文をダウンロードするためのプログラムの様に見受けられるのですが、実際にはどのサイトなのでしょう？ 差し支えなければ教えて下さい(API などでバッチ的に処理できるかもしれません)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし恥ずかしながら私が開発したショボショボアプリにデータをいれようとするためのものなのです。

Comment: 最終形態はこうなったのですが、いまいち理解が深まらずデータリストが非定義であると表示されます。どのようにしたらいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下では `openpyxl` ではなく、`pandas` パッケージの [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) を利用して Excel のシートを読み込みます。

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='XXX')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='...') # ここは適当に

header = ('id_title', 'id_content_title', 'id_heading', 'id_content_url', 'id_creator')
data_keys = ['title', 'title', 'lead', 'url', 'author']
for data in df[data_keys].iterrows():
  for id, attr in zip(header, data[1]):
    driver.find_element_by_id(id).send_keys(attr)
  # おそらくフォームの submit ボタンを押す、という動作が必要
```

ここで `df` は以下の様になっていて、これを行毎に処理しています。

| title | date | author | creator url | lead | url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| タイトル1 | 2021-09-30 00:00:00 | 著者1 | creator URL1 | 筆頭著者1 | URL1 |
| タイトル2 | 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | 著者2 | creator URL2 | 筆頭著者2 | URL2 |
| タイトル3 | 2021-10-02 00:00:00 | 著者3 | creator URL3 | 筆頭著者3 | URL3 |
| タイトル4 | 2021-10-03 00:00:00 | 著者4 | creator URL4 | 筆頭著者4 | URL4 |
| タイトル5 | 2021-10-04 00:00:00 | 著者5 | creator URL5 | 筆頭著者5 | URL5 |

Answer (score 0):

エクセルを行ごとに読み取って辞書型データを作成できているので、あとはそれを適切に取り出すだけです。
後半のコード末尾を流用し、関数などを使って辞書型データを`v_excel…`に渡しましょう。

下記のコードを実行すると、コメントのような実行結果が返ります。

```
for data in data_list:
    print(data)
    print(data['title'])
    # print(data['b8']) # これはエラーになる

# {None: 1, 'title': 'hoge', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 0, 0), 'author': 'foo', 'creator url': None, 'lead': 'hogefoo', 'url': 'https://hogefoo.com'}
# hoge
# {None: 2, 'title': 'fuga', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 0, 0), 'author': 'bar', 'creator url': None, 'lead': 'fugabar', 'url': 'https://fugabar.com'}
# fuga
# {None: 3, 'title': 'piyo', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 0, 0), 'author': 'baz', 'creator url': None, 'lead': 'piyobaz', 'url': 'https://piyobaz.com'}
# piyo
```

つまり既にヘッダをキーにした辞書型データが`data_list`に行数分のリストとして入っています。
下記のようなコードで辞書型データをご質問前半に繰り返しで渡すことで、要望を実現できるはずです。

```
def send_keys(driver, data):
    v_excel_title = data['title']
    v_excel_lead = data['lead']
    v_excel_author = data['author']
    # 以下略(フォーム項目のリセットなどは適切に行ってください)

# あらかじめWebドライバを用意しておく例
# from selenium import webdriver
# driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for data in data_list:
    send_keys(driver, data)

driver.quit()
```

---

検証コード

```
import openpyxl

#前半のコード
def send_keys(driver, data):
    v_excel_title = data['title']
    v_excel_lead = data['lead']
    v_excel_author = data['author']
    # 以下略(フォーム項目のリセットなどは適切に行ってください)
    print(v_excel_title)

#read excelのコードを書き換えたもの
def create_data_list():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx', data_only=True)
    ws = wb["Sheet1"]

    data_list = []
    header_cells = ws[1]

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws.max_row):
        row_dic = dict([(k.value, v.value) for k, v in zip(header_cells, row)])
        data_list.append(row_dic)

    return data_list

data_list = create_data_list()
for data in data_list:
    print(data)
    send_keys(None, data)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。補足で質問があるのでご確認おねがいいたします。

Comment: `v_title`などがインデントされていない(`v_excel_url`と同様に前スペースが入っていない)場合、エレメント見つけて入れる処理が関数の範囲外となり、おそらくエラーになります。追記されたコードが意図的なものでなければインデントの見直しをお願いいたします。

Comment: 最終形態は追記のようになったのですが、いまいち理解が深まらずデータリストが非定義であると表示されます。どのようにしたらいいのでしょうか？

Comment: この質問は解決されて他の質問に移行されたようですが、そちらではインデントが見直されているように見えます。つまり追記された最終形態と他の質問では様式が違います。試行錯誤の末に解決されたならばよろしいのですが、未解決でしたら「データリストが非定義であると表示され」るエラーメッセージを具体的に追記願います。